# Access a parameter from an interface (Fortran)

Tags: fortran

I am using a parameter to fix the precision of the used types.
This works fine until I try to use the same type within an interface. Consider this small example:

```
module Hello
    implicit none

    save
    integer, parameter  :: K = selected_real_kind(10)

contains

    subroutine dosomething(fun)
        real(K)     :: foo
        interface
           function fun(bar)
                real(K) :: bar
                real(K) :: fun
           end function fun
        end interface
    end subroutine

end module
```

Here, foo would be of the desired type, whereas the compiler (gfortran) complains for 'bar' and 'fun'.

The error is

```
Error: Parameter 'k' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does 
not reduce to a constant expression
```

Is there a way to get this working?
(For now, I am just writing selected_real_kind(10) everywhere but this is not elegant at all)

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to add `import` inside the interface.   It is somewhat of a misdesign that the definitions of the module are outside the scope of the interface.  Plain `import` will import everything.

```
....
    subroutine dosomething(fun)
        real(K)     :: foo
        interface
           function fun(bar)
                import
                real(K) :: bar
                real(K) :: fun
           end function fun
        end interface
    end subroutine
....
```

Also possible: `import :: K`

Comment: One of the main reasons for interface blocks was to provide an interface for procedures "defined elsewhere" (such as external procedures).  Procedures defined elsewhere may not know about the things that have been defined in the host of the interface block (they may not have the same host), hence excluding automatic host association into interface bodies seem reasonable to me.