# Pure function error, but using a vector

Tags: fortran

I inherited a rather large (but still manageable) fortran (F90) codebase, and being a total fortran newbie, I've tried to compile it. First errors were easy to correct, but this one is beyond my understanding.

```
% make    
[  1%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/Core.dir/vars.f90.o
/Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/vars.f90:127:32:

             real*8, dimension(0:links(kg)), intent(out) :: feq_vect
                                1
Error: Specification function 'links' at (1) must be PURE
```

Now, as I waddle through the code, I find the `link` declaration:

```
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: links
```

I see this is a vector, not a function, so why is `gfortran` complaining about this being a function? A self-contained example follows.

How can I correct this error?

**`mph.f90`**

```
program mph

    use vars 
    !
    implicit none

endprogram mph
```

**`vars.f90`**

```
module vars

    implicit none  

    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: links

    abstract interface
        subroutine linkstest(kg,feq_vect)
            real*8, dimension(0:links(kg)), intent(out) :: feq_vect
        endsubroutine        
    end interface

end module vars
```

## Solution

Although the error is completely different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976435/access-a-parameter-from-an-interface-fortran), the solution seems to be the same: adding `import` into the subroutine.

Comment: From what you have posted, yes `links` looks like an array.  The compiler clearly disagrees, and presumably for good reason.  Can you therefore provide a [mcve]?  That would help us avoid speculating about scopes and so on.

Comment: Thanks, @francescalus, I've added the minimal code I could now, I hope that helps in finding the error. By the way, it seems that this code works with Intel's compiler under Windows, this is GNU Fortran under macOS.

Comment: As stated, the solution was the same, with different errors.